# UICollectionViewCell doesn't change on frame update

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to make a custom swipeable `UICollectionViewCell` with a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. Here's my code:

In the custom `UICollectionViewCell`:

```
func setup() {
    attributes = delegate.attributesForCell(self)
    selectionView = UIView(frame: attributes.frame)
    self.addSubview(selectionView)
    let cellPan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "cellDidPan:")
    selectionView.addGestureRecognizer(cellPan)
}

func cellDidPan(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    switch gesture.state {
    case .Began:
        originalFrame = attributes.frame
    case .Changed:
        let translation: CGPoint = gesture.translationInView(selectionView)
        attributes.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: originalFrame.origin.x + translation.x, y: originalFrame.origin.y), size: originalFrame.size)
        println("t \(translation.x)")
        println("c \(attributes.center)")
        println("f \(attributes.frame)")
    case .Ended:
        println("nothing here yet")
    default:
        println("Unrecognized gesture state")
    }
}
```

In the `UICollectionViewController` (the cell's delegate):

```
func attributesForCell(cell: SwipeableCollectionViewCell) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
    let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForCell(cell)
    return collectionView.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
}
```

When I swipe across my `UICollectionViewCell`, the frame logs the correct changes (everything stays the same except for the x coordinate, which gets smaller swiping left and gets bigger swiping right) however the cell just stays in the same place.

I am using the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, and setting up everything in storyboards and Interface Builder.

Comment: If you've found the answer to your question, write it down as an answer, providing good detail, so that it helps the others if they come across the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer! layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath() returns **a copy** of the attributes, not the actual attributes object. This means modifying these attributes will, obviously, do nothing. Instead, use the UICollectionViewCell properties.